# How is my EditText content being saved?

Tags: android

I created a simple app that has nothing except an EditText element. When I run the app, I type text into the element and then press Ctrl-F11 to change the emulator's orientation. I've added logging information to make sure that the activity gets destroyed and re-created when I change orientation. I haven't added any code to save the text in the EditText element and yet, after the change of orientation, the text that I typed stays in the EditText element. What mechanism in Android is saving and then restoring the element's text (is it savedInstanceState) and how can I see for myself the details of this saving operation?

Answer (score 1):

onSaveInstanceState()/onRestoreInstanceState() along with unique widget IDs. Some links that utilize:

[Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/5d7fd8da11c8e971

Comment: Is there a simple example demonstrating the need to explicitly save information in the onPause() method? I've even tried doing "kill -9" to a process, and onSaveInstanceState() still seemed to be called automatically. When will not doing explicit saving inside the onPause() method cause trouble, and how can I make this happen in an example on the emulator?